# I am trying to run terraform as a container in minikube but the container is getting crash loop back

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to run terraform as a container in minikube but the container is getting crash loop back
This is the cmdlet i am using
kubectl create deployment terraform --image=hashicorp/terraform:light
please suggest how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

The `hashicorp/terraform:light` container's entrypoint is `terraform`. Thus you must provide a valid argument when starting the container.

(You could find if you check the logs of crashed pod.)

You can override the docker `ENTRYPOINT` in command line to keep the pod running.

```
kubectl create deployment terraform --image=hashicorp/terraform:light -n test -- sleep 3600

$ kubectl get po -n test
NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
terraform-5f7bfdc955-95pt6   1/1     Running            0          25s

$ kubectl exec -it terraform-5f7bfdc955-95pt6 -n test sh  
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
/ # terraform -version
Terraform v0.15.3
on linux_amd64
```